# log into server with created user on linux ubuntu

Tags: linux, ssh

Server provider offered me an option to create ssh connection. I applied pub key generated with putty and I can enter it as a root.

First thing I did was to create a new user with sudo rights.

I opened /etc/ssh/sshd_config and inserted:

```
AllowUsers my_user
```

from /root/.ssh/authorized_keys I copy to /home/my_user/.ssh/authorized_keys

I apply

```
systemctl restart ssh
```

I try to enter again via putty.

login as: new_user

I get error: server refused our key ... What could be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be a permission issue. set keys permission first

`chown -R my_user:my_user /home/my_user/.ssh`

`chmod 700 /home/my_user/.ssh`

`chmod 600 /home/my_user/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: Yes this is exactly right. Btw, why did you apply chmod 600 /home/my_user/.ssh/authorized_keys as well if may I ask?

Comment: The ***authorized_keys*** should be only readable/writable by the own user. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much. I get it now. Have a nice day!